# NetSuite Saved Search CRITERIA Filter > Most Recent User Note TYPE

Tags: sql, case, netsuite

Needing help from the community. Company I work for recently started using NetSuite. Over the last year, we have found the need to enhance processes to meet our business needs.

Current issue is stumping me as a result of my basic SQL knowledge.

Goal: Only include in search results Purchase Orders that have the LAST User Note of a certain type of Note.

Because I am trying to limit the results, this will be part of the criteria and it is part of an 'or' expression. The first half already works so I am just focusing on the this half of the equation.

Essentially, this is what I am trying to do:

1. Take All Purchase Orders
2. If the Validation box is checked, and no User Notes of Type X, include - OR -
3. If the Validation box is checked, and User Notes are present

   - Order the User Notes by User Note Date (DESC, ensure most recent on top)
   - Take the First User Note (most recent) and if the User Note Type is Y, include

(Focus is on #3 the 'or' part)

I have researched RANK and DENSE_RANK and tried a bunch of different CASE statements but I am getting nowhere and I don't think adding any of the code I have tried is going to be helpful.

Apologies in advance if I missed something critical in the write-up. The Saved Search is being used by a Schedule Script to then 'do stuff.'

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would help add clarity, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [Why should I tag my RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Stu - Thanks. Aside from the sample data which my company wouldn't allow, what more might be helpful? I indicated the Goal = desired results and walked through the logic to get there in normal speak.

Comment: Sample data doesn't have to be *real* data. Make something up.

Comment: I honestly don't really know what the data would look like. I have not seen the Database. I know, not very helpful when I am the one needing help. Guess I know even less about SQL than I thought. If it is at all helpful, this is the Record Browser details for NetSuite: [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/purchaseorder.html)